# Read all the repos in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I want to make a script in Python, that is able to read all repositories from a Bitbucket account, to find some content inside code files.

Is it possible to make this?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use the code search tool?

Comment: Because i need to automatize one task :)